# Unit Vector proof. Odd notation

Tags: vectors

I am reading this proof for the unit vector length and this is odd to me:

[image]

How did the book go from the double usage of the length symbol to the broken out usage of two single length symbols? How did they go from the second step (highlighted in yellow) to the third step?

Comment: $1/\|v\|$ is a positive scalar, so like any positive scalar, you can slide it in or out of the norm at will (this is the homogeneity property that is part of the definition of a norm). $$\left\|\frac{v}{\|v\|}\right\| = \left\|\left(\frac{1}{\|v\|}\right)v\right\| = \left(\frac{1}{\|v\|}\right)\|v\|$$

Comment: the name of this property is the homogeneity property. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\left\|\frac{v}{a} \right\|= \frac1{|a|}\left\| v\right\|$$

here $a=\left\|v\right\|$ is a scalar and we don't have to write the absolute value is $a$ is positive.

Comment: You can add that in this context it also happens to be a *positive* scalar.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.

Comment: wait I don't get it, where did the absolute value sign come from? What's your point?

Comment: We have $\left\|  \frac{v}{a}\right\|=\frac1{\color{red}|a\color{red}|}\left\|v\right\|$, here $a=\left\| v\right\|$. Hence we have $\left\|  \frac{v}{\left\| v\right\|}\right\|=\frac1{\color{red}|\left\| v\right\|\color{red}|}\left\|v\right\|=\frac1{\left\| v\right\|}\left\|v\right\|$